# Reading statistics from a file

Tags: java

One of the homework assignments my instructor gave me was a baseball statistics program. It reads from a file called stats.dat, which contains the name of a baseball player's name and a list of what happened when they were at the bat. It reads and prints their name and the amount of outs(o), hits(h), walks(w), and sacrifice flies(s) that they have. This is what the file contains:

```
Willy Wonk,o,o,h,o,o,o,o,h,w,o,o,o,o,s,h,o,h
Shari Jones,h,o,o,s,s,h,o,o,o,h,o,o,o
Barry Bands,h,h,w,o,o,o,w,h,o,o,h,h,o,o,w,w,w,h,o,o
Sally Slugger,o,h,h,o,o,h,h,w
Missy Lots,o,o,s,o,o,w,o,o,o
Joe Jones,o,h,o,o,o,o,h,h,o,o,o,o,w,o,o,o,h,o,h,h
Larry Loop,w,s,o,o,o,h,o,o,h,s,o,o,o,h,h
Sarah Swift,o,o,o,o,h,h,w,o,o,o
Bill Bird,h,o,h,o,h,w,o,o,o,h,s,s,h,o,o,o,o,o,o
Don Daring,o,o,h,h,o,o,h,o,h,o,o,o,o,o,o,h
Jill Jet,o,s,s,h,o,o,h,h,o,o,o,h,o,h,w,o,o,h,h,o
```

So far I have the basic idea down, even though I don't quite understand what each line is doing(I modified some code of a program in the book my class is reading that prints a URL that's in a text file and then prints out each part of the url that's separated by a /). I have it so that the program prints out the player's name, but I'm stumped on how to print out the amount of hits, outs, walks, and sacrifice flies they get. So far it's reading 1 character out of the line, then it goes down to the next player and prints out 2, then 3, etc. Here's the code I have for it so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BaseballStats
{
 public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
 {
  int hit = 0, walk = 0, sac = 0, out = 0, length = 0, wholeLength = 0;
  Scanner fileScan, lineScan, statScan;
  String fileName, playerName, line, stats, playerStats;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
  fileName = scan.nextLine();
  fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

  while (fileScan.hasNext())
  {
   System.out.println();
   line = ("Player: " + fileScan.nextLine());
   wholeLength = line.length();

   lineScan = new Scanner(line);
   lineScan.useDelimiter(",");

   stats = lineScan.next();
   statScan = new Scanner(stats);
   statScan.useDelimiter(",");


   while (statScan.hasNext())
   {
    System.out.println(statScan.next());
    length = stats.length() - 1;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      if (stats.charAt(i) == 'h')
        hit++;
      else if (stats.charAt(i) == 'o')
        out++;
      else if (stats.charAt(i) == 'w')
        walk++;
      else if (stats.charAt(i) == 's')
        sac++;
    }
   }
    System.out.println("Hits: " + hit + "\nOuts: " + out + "\nWalks: " + walk +              "\nSacrifice flies: " + sac);
  }
 }
}
```

(I'm having a hard time getting the last part of the last statement in my code to appear correctly in the editor, sorry if it looks a bit weird) I have been wondering what's wrong and I can't figure it out so far. Is there anything to get me on the right track?

Comment: Try to print stats before your for-loop and you might get a hint.

Comment: Personally, I would use 'line.split(",")' and work with the resulting array, rather than mess with Scanners.

Answer (score 1):

If looks like you're creating one `Scanner` instance too many:

- You use the first Scanner: `fileScan` to read one line at a time and assign this to line.
- You then create a Scanner: `lineScan` to read over the line one field at a time.
- However, you only read the first token from `lineScan` and then create a third Scanner instance: `statsScan`.  Rather than do this, you simply need to read all the tokens from `lineScan`, storing the first as the person's name and processing the subsequent tokens as statistics.

One other thing I'd advise is to create a dedicated class to hold the person's name and statistics and implement `toString()` on this class to produce a sensible String representation; e.g.

```
public class Player {
  private final String name;
  private int hit, out, walk, sac;

  public int getNumHits() {
    return hit;
  }

  public int incrementNumHits() {
    return ++hit;
  }

  // TODO: Implement other getter and increment methods.

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s.  Hits: %d, Outs: %d, Walks: %d, Sacrifice flies: %d",
      name, hit, out, walk, sac);
  }
}
```

By implementing `toString()` you simply need to create and populate your Player class with statistics and then print it out; e.g.

```
Player player = new Player("Jim");
player.incrementNumHits();
// etc.
System.out.println(player);
```

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean by "populate your player class with statistics". From my understanding(which is very low), the parameters(eg. "Jim" in your second example) has to be on the same line with the new operator and the object.

Comment: What I mean is that you're defining a class: Player, which acts as a container for the player name and associated statistics: hit, out, etc.  This allows you to then define associated behaviour (e.g. incrementNumHits(), toString()).  By "populate your class" I mean that upon reading each new line of the file you create a new instance of Player and call the appropriate incrementXXX methods on it to collate the stats as you read them.