# Using substrings while reading file data

Tags: java

Last night I asked a question like this, I'm not sure what's happening and I have encountered another problem so here goes:

My instructor has given my class a project a program that reads a file, reads each letter and then prints out the amount of hits, outs, walks and sacrifice flies that each line has. I posted some more info in my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828724/reading-statistics-from-a-file) about this topic.
I have rewritten the code in chance that I would better my chances of getting the program to work. I learned about what substrings are and a bit more about tokens and came together with this program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BaseballStats
{
  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner fileScan, lineScan;
    String fileName;
    int oCount = 0, hCount = 0, sCount = 0, wCount = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file: ");
    fileName = scan.nextLine();
    fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
      lineScan = new Scanner (fileName);
      lineScan.useDelimiter(",");

      String input = lineScan.nextLine();
      int point =(input.indexOf(","));

      String name = input.substring(0,point);
      String records = input.substring(point,input.length());

      for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++)
      {
        if (records.charAt(i) == 's')
          sCount++;
        else if (records.charAt(i) == 'o')
          oCount++;
        else if (records.charAt(i) == 'h')
          hCount++;
        else if (records.charAt(i) == 'w')
          wCount++;
      }// end of for loop
      System.out.printf("Name: %s. Hits: %d. Outs: %d. Walks: %d. Sacrifice flies: %d.", name, hCount, oCount, wCount, sCount);
      System.out.println();

  }//end of while loop

 }//end of main
}// end
```

The program runs fine, but after I enter in stats.dat(The file that is supposed to be reading), I get the following exception error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at BaseballStats.main(BaseballStats.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

It points to line 25, which is the

```
String name = input.substring(0,point);
```

line. I have been stumped on this, am I missing something?

Note: I have read Adamski's suggestion on the original question. I tried to follow it but as I'm new to java I'm having a hard time understanding encapsulation, specifically the setter and getter methods. I figured it would be best to leave them alone for now until next chapter, where my class explains them.

Comment: Look at the line 'int point =(input.indexOf(","));' see what 'point' is resolving to when you attempt to substring the 'input'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're dealing with is called an "edge condition."  It's a situation that isn't the most common situation for your algorithm.  But you have to deal with the rare situations as well to avoid errors.

You've got the following code:

```
String input = lineScan.nextLine();
int point =(input.indexOf(","));
String name = input.substring(0,point);
```

This is a problem of bug diagnosis (which programmers do all day long.)  You need to now ask yourself the following:

1. What does "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" mean?  Google will tell you that.
2. How could that possibly be?  What would cause that error when calling substring?  (Google java substring to see what causes substring could throw that exception.)
3. This will have you looking at the indexOf() method (again, google is your friend) and what kind of results would come back from that that could lead to that stack trace.
4. What kind of input could lead to THAT situation?

Hope that gets you moving forward again.

Comment: I think I understand where you're going at. The main problem seems to be at the input declaration, which is reading the next token of lineScan. Since lineScan's delimiter is a comma, it never sees a comma in the string, thus giving -1. Thanks for giving me what I need to improve on, now I have to figure out how to get the name printed.

Answer (score -1):

[`String#indexOf(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) returns -1 if the passed in parameter is not found in `this` String.

So, `input` is likely not finding a `,` in it:

```
int point =(input.indexOf(","));
```

And when you pass in a negative index into [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29), an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.

```
String name = input.substring(0,point); // input.substring(0, -1); will throw the exception
```